# Repeating a piece of code in R and storing the results as a vector

Tags: r, repeat

I've been running estimations in R by fitting a curve to a price series. I want to evaluate the fitness of the curve by making very small changes to the key parameters m and omega at their optimum values. To do that I want to see how the sum of squared residuals changes at the optimum. I defined the function for residuals as below:

```
# Define function for sum of squared residuals, to evaluate the fitness of parameters m and omega
residuals <- function(m, omega, tc) {
  lm.result <- LPPL(rTicker, m, omega, tc)
  return(sum((FittedLPPL(rTicker, lm.result, m, omega, tc) - rTicker$Close) ** 2))
}
```

I can then yield an absolute value for the SSR at the optimum as follows:

```
#To return value of SSR
residvalue <- residuals(m, omega,tc)
```

What I want to do is repeat this code over a sequence of values for m (and then omega).

For instance if the optimum m = 0.5, I want to run this code to calculate the object 'residvalue' for a sequence of m values that lie between 0 < m < 1, interval size = 0.01 (ie run it 100 times for 100 different SSR values). I would then like to store these resulting SSR values in a vector (which I can then turn into a data frame of observations). This appears like a trivial task but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq(0,1,0.01),function(m) residuals(m,omega,tc))
```